# Set default value for column using alias in sql select query

Tags: sql-server

I am facing an problem to set an default value in sql select query

```
ex: t1.Employee as EmpDeptName
```

here i need to set an default value so that it returns always the default value

what i tried  `t1.Employee as EmpDeptName 'ITdept'`

But this fails always telling incorrect syntax

Comment: Why are you adding the 'ITdept' portion to this. The syntax for alias is just `AS`  and then the name of your column.

Comment: `SELECT 'ITdept' as EmpDeptName`

Comment: Huh? So you don't *ever* want to show the actual data from the column in the table? Or you only want to show `'ITdept'` when the column has no value? Please be specific about your requirements so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to `SELECT` this value when you call a query,

```
SELECT 'ITdept' AS EmpDeptName, ...
```

If you want to use "ITdept" as the default value when the column is empty,

```
SELECT ISNULL(EmpDeptName, 'ITdept') AS EmpDeptName, ...
```

If you want to set the column default,

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    EmpDeptName <data type> DEFAULT 'ITdept'
);
```